# How many watches are there in a page?

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs, watch

I am doing performance testing in Angular and I want to know exactly how many watches are there in my page. Turns out there is no easy way to do this. Has anyone tried it yet?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Idea for quick and dirty solution: register global counter, and increment/decrement it in methods that are responsible for registering/deregistering watches. Ofcourse - you will have to edit Angular.js code.

Comment: you can wrap angular's .$watch locally and use the local version, which can log or push to anywhere you need.

Comment: Check `$scope.watchers`

Comment: yes, wrapping locally is even better then editing angular´s code directly (as @dandavis suggests)

Comment: @dandavis can you show me an example on how to do that?

Comment: @sza that won't work, unfortunately. `$scope.$$watchers` is another option but it is `null` inside the controller. its only filled during the `$digest` phase. Also, I do not see where `$scope.$$watchers` is actually being set.

Comment: @javaCity Try `$scope.$watch($scope, function(){
        console.log($scope.$$watchers)
    })`. Get the number and then minus 1 representing the current watch.

Comment: @sza It gives me null. http://jsfiddle.net/fknxq/

Comment: @javaCity it is an array. you need add `.length`. http://jsfiddle.net/gWhGV/

Comment: @sza my bad. But I don't get accurate reading. http://jsfiddle.net/kSXLZ/2/ the number of watchers should be 5, but I am getting reading of 4. Am I missing some core concepts out here?

Comment: @sza I think angular concatenates "`stuff` and `anotherStuff`" and puts a single watch on both. After moving them around, I get the accurate reading. http://jsfiddle.net/kSXLZ/3/ Thank you for your help. Could you please answer it below so that I can mark it as solved? Thanks!

Comment: @javaCity I am not 100% sure. It seems every ng-model has a watcher and the rest template has another one for interpolation. Hence it is 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question. I created a function that will do it:

```
// get the watch count
// scopeHash is an optional parameter, but if you provide one, this function will modify it for later use (possibly debugging)
function getWatchCount (scope, scopeHash) {
    // default for scopeHash
    if (scopeHash === undefined) {
        scopeHash = {};
    }

    // make sure scope is defined and we haven't already processed this scope
    if (!scope || scopeHash[scope.$id] !== undefined) {
        return 0;
    }

    var watchCount = 0;

    if (scope.$$watchers) {
        watchCount = scope.$$watchers.length;
    }
    scopeHash[scope.$id] = watchCount;

    // get the counts of children and sibling scopes
    // we only need childHead and nextSibling (not childTail or prevSibling)
    watchCount+= getWatchCount(scope.$$childHead, scopeHash);
    watchCount+= getWatchCount(scope.$$nextSibling, scopeHash);

    return watchCount;
}
```

It will calculate the number of watchers on any scope. It may be most useful to calculate on the root scope, but you can use it at any scope level (possibly to check watches on a component). Here is an example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/S7APg/

Comment: Does this include isoloatedScopes? if not how to include them?